# Eloquent Model access relational data on method call

Tags: orm, laravel-5, eloquent

We have two models and method **history**:

```
class Employment_request extends Model {
    protected $table = 'employment_requests';
    // some code here
    public function history(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Employment_history');
    }
}


class Employment_history extends Model {
     protected $table = 'employment_history';
     // some code
}
```

Lets create instance of Employment_request:

```
$r = Employment_request::find(28)
```

In this case method history data is requested when instance of Employment_request is created. Isn't it?
- Object takes more memory
- need more time to create it
- history data added after object creation isnt accessible

because when i add new history record:

```
Employment_history::create([
    'user_id' => 17,
    'employment_request_id' => 28,
    'change' => '? Stefanka'
]);
```

and  call method:

```
$r->history;
```

A new record isnt  returned with collection but after recreating object it is.
But when i call:

```
$r->history()->get()
```

I dont need to recreate it to get new data.

How it works inside?
Tested in tinker console.

Comment: `In this case method history data is requested when instance of Employment_request is created. Isn't it?`, it'll be available only when you'll call `history`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three types of methods in laravel to load relationship data. Eager loading, Lazy loading and Lazy eager loading. Eager loading is When you retrieve parent model data you have to add you have to pass relationship name into `with` method(`Employment_request::with('history')->find(28)`) then you can access to the relationship by calling it as a class variable(`$r->history;`). if you use this method it only gives relationship records on the database at the time you retrieved parent model data. If you want get relations after adding new relationship record manually you have to use Lazy loading method (`$r->history()->get()`) which retrieves latest data from your database. That why you cannot access your get your new record from method(eager loading).

Comment: Thank you for anser. What about my 3 conclusions (except last one). Are they correct?

Comment: Using simple query in method body: **return Employment_history::where('employment_request_id', $this->id );** seems to be a better solution insted of specifying relation.

Comment: Depends on the method you are using to fetch relationship data, for eager loading it's true, but for lazy loading or lazy eager loading you can get new record. For saving new records through relationship laravel has their own methods(attach, sync and save). Try to load data using eager loading much as possible, it's faster than other methods